# Data manipulation (cleaning dataset before visualization) - Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dataframe, etl

I'm planning to create a dashboard for financial analysis (could be any type of dashboard, as I keep running into the same challenge).

I'm looking for advice on how you "clean" the data before visualizing it. Some examples: fill missing value with average of 10 closest points, replace x for y, joining data from other sources etc (typical ETL challenges).

I'm intermediate to advanced in Javascript and usually build my applications with Node.js as backend.

Anyone with best practice for cleaning data with Javascript?

Best regards,
Oscar

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const DashBoard = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/data')
      .then(response => response.formData())
      .then(rawData => {
        // "clean" the data
        const cleanedData = data.doWhateverYouLike();
        setData(cleanedData);
      })
  }, []);


  return (
    /* Some components to use your data */
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew! Well kind of. This is what I believe I would do on the front end side. Basically, the part  "const cleanedData = data.doWhateverYouLike();" Is what I'm looking for suggestions for. Lets say the data I'm getting from an API has flaws which makes my graphs look bad. How to "clean" this data? In python people tend to use Pandas for example, but I struggle to find a way with Node.js

Comment: I'm not aware of a well-known library that will handle this type of stuff in JS. Most likely you will have to implement it yourself. So far, the examples you gave are not that hard to implement.